# How to add multiple rows

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datarow

As the question says, how can I add multiple rows to a datatable in vb.net? I mean, without looping. F. e. I have an array of datarows and I can then write: dt.Rows.Add(rowarray).

Is this possible? I have searched the net, but found everywhere just looping (or I used the wrong search words).

Comment: Create an array of DataRow's and then add them to the DataTable. What have you tried first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible - [`DataRowCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't seem to have anything like `AddRange` to hide the looping, although I suppose you could write your own extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module MyExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Sub AddRange(existing As DataRowCollection, newRows As IEnumerable(Of DataRow))
        For Each row In newRows
            existing.Add(row)
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

And use that in your code:

```
dt.Rows.AddRange(rowarray)
```